# How do I change the ouput's name in a CoreML model from Identity to something else?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, coreml

The output layer's name in the tensorflow model has been customized, and yet when I try to convert it using CoreML, it will not recognize the layer unless I use "Identity" when I try and assign an `output_description`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the mlmodel file using coremltools in a Python script, then use the `rename_feature` function to rename the output.

See the documentation at https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/mlmodel-utilities